# Pandora's Next-Song Selection: When, Where, and How?

Tags: pandora

I surprisingly cannot find any information about this online:

I have some questions on the Selection of the Next Song in Pandora (Premium) App:

- Does the selection of the next song occur in the App inside the phone, or elsewhere, like a Server?
- Does it occur after the song has ended, or before while it's still playing?
- What are the influential factors behind a song's selection? Are there other factors than the thumbs down/up?

Answer (score 0):

> Does the selection of the next song occurs in the App inside the phone, or elsewhere, like a Server?

- selection occurs on the server side

> Does it occur after the song has ended, or before while it's still playing?

- selection of next song is known already by starting the current song (imagine it like they are in a playlist)

> What are the influential factors behind a song's selection? Are there other factors than the thumbs down/up?

- prediction is mostly based on your history and habits (patterns how you interact with the platform)